# drag and drop element on physical architecture blank diagram not working

Tags: instance, diagram, ecore, sirius

I recently test the creation of sirius diagram with this tutorial : https://alain-bernard.developpez.com.../sirius-intro/).
Unfortunately today I'm locked when I try to drag and drop items on my physical architecture blank diagram. 
I have the following error :

```
 org.eclipse.sirius.ecore.extender.business.api.accessor.exception.FeatureNotFoundException: softwares on org.polarsys.capella.core.data.pa.impl.PhysicalComponentImpl@64877d81 (id: fb2beb6f-e025-41c1-8547-c1be3f59db8f, sid: null) (name: New Software) (visibleInDoc: true, visibleInLM: true, summary: null, review: null) (abstract: false) (dataComponent: false) (kind: UNSET, nature: UNSET)
at org.eclipse.sirius.ecore.extender.business.api.accessor.ModelAccessor.eIsMany(ModelAccessor.java:321)
at org.eclipse.sirius.business.internal.helper.task.operations.CreateInstanceTask.execute(CreateInstanceTask.java:89)
at org.eclipse.sirius.business.internal.helper.task.ExecuteToolOperationTask.executeTask(ExecuteToolOperationTask.java:129)
at org.eclipse.sirius.business.internal.helper.task.ExecuteToolOperationTask.executeTask(ExecuteToolOperationTask.java:140)
at org.eclipse.sirius.business.internal.helper.task.ExecuteToolOperationTask.execute(ExecuteToolOperationTask.java:113)
at org.eclipse.sirius.business.api.helper.task.TaskExecutor.execute(TaskExecutor.java:66)
at org.eclipse.sirius.tools.api.command.SiriusCommand.doExecute(SiriusCommand.java:82)
at org.eclipse.emf.transaction.RecordingCommand.execute(RecordingCommand.java:135)
at org.eclipse.sirius.diagram.ui.tools.api.command.GMFCommandWrapper.doExecuteWithResult(GMFCommandWrapper.java:104)
at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.emf.commands.core.command.AbstractTransactionalCommand.doExecute(AbstractTransactionalCommand.java:247)
at org.eclipse.emf.workspace.AbstractEMFOperation.execute(AbstractEMFOperation.java:150)
at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.common.core.command.CompositeCommand.doExecuteWithResult(CompositeCommand.java:403)
at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.common.core.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:134)
at org.eclipse.sirius.diagram.ui.tools.internal.commands.WrappingCommandIgnoringAffectedFiles.execute(WrappingCommandIgnoringAffectedFiles.java:125)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.operations.DefaultOperationHistory.execute(DefaultOperationHistory.java:488)
at org.eclipse.sirius.diagram.ui.tools.internal.editor.DDiagramCommandStack.execute(DDiagramCommandStack.java:73)
at org.eclipse.sirius.diagram.ui.tools.internal.editor.DDiagramCommandStack.execute(DDiagramCommandStack.java:54)
at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramCommandStack.execute(DiagramCommandStack.java:156)
at org.eclipse.gef.tools.AbstractTool.executeCommand(AbstractTool.java:425)
at org.eclipse.gef.tools.AbstractTool.executeCurrentCommand(AbstractTool.java:438)
at org.eclipse.gef.tools.CreationTool.performCreation(CreationTool.java:269)
at org.eclipse.gef.tools.CreationTool.handleButtonUp(CreationTool.java:189)
at org.eclipse.gef.tools.AbstractTool.mouseUp(AbstractTool.java:1200)
at org.eclipse.gef.EditDomain.mouseUp(EditDomain.java:301)
at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.DomainEventDispatcher.dispatchMouseReleased(DomainEventDispatcher.java:380)
at org.eclipse.draw2d.LightweightSystem$EventHandler.mouseUp(LightweightSystem.java:548)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:221)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.polarsys.capella.core.platform.sirius.ui.app.CapellaApplication.start(CapellaApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

I think it is a problem with the reference name of the instance in the .odesign file but I don't know why? if you need my .ecore and .odesign file I can joined them.

Comment: can you show your odesign and your metamodel please

Answer (score 0):

Your link does not work. Also the error says you do not have a "softwares" feature on a PhysicalComponent. So in your odesign, you probably want to use the name of a feature that actually exists.

Comment: Thank your for your answer here is the correct link :https://alain-bernard.developpez.com/tutoriels/eclipse/sirius-intro/. Yes in the ecore I have a component which extend PhysicalComponent and after I create a node element in the odesign file to create the item in the palette to be able to draw it on the physcical architecture blank diagram.

Comment: Your sentences are very confusing. I understand you want to create some new element that is related to a PhysicalComponent. Through with feature (i.e. EReference) is your new element related to a PhysicalComponent ? Because that is the name you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe can I send you the .ecore and the .odesign it will be easier for you to understand what I mean?